# Null Reference Exception when trying to store an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So I'm trying to store fields from a text file into an array. But when I reach the line

```
data = record.Trim().Split('*');
```

I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
public bool matchCustomer(string accountID, string record)
    {
        String[] data = new String[5];
        data = null;
        data = record.Trim().Split('*');
        this.accountNumber = data[0];
        if (accountID == this.accountNumber)
            {
                return true;
            }
        else
        {
           return false;
          }
       }
```

Here is where the method is called:

```
public bool findCustomer(string accountNumber)
    {
        string record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord(ref endOfFile);
        bool okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
        return okay;
    }
```

Here is `getNextRecord`:

```
   public string getNextRecord(ref Boolean endOfFileFlag)
    {
        string nextRecord;

        endOfFileFlag = false;
        nextRecord = reader.ReadLine();

        if (nextRecord == null)
        {
            endOfFileFlag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            recordReadCount += 1;
        } // end if

        return (nextRecord);
    } // end getNextRecord
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in there? Seems like `record` is null. Also you call get next record, but what happens if you're at the end of the file?

Comment: I suspect  `record` must be a null.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can simplify your code by replacing:

```
String[] data = new String[5];
data = null;
data = record.Trim().Split('*');
```

with just a single line:

```
string[] data = record.Trim().Split('*');
```

This is a correct statement, because you don't know the max index (elements) of the `string[]` array returning by `Split()` function.

Second, make sure that `record!=null`, and also it has a string containing "*" characters used as delimiter in `Split()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this line of code

```
data = record.Trim().Split('*');
```

If a `NullReferenceException` occurred here, that means you must be calling a method on a null object. In this case, the only possible object is `record`.

Now we know what is null, but why is it null? Let's look at this method:

```
public bool findCustomer(string accountNumber)
{
    string record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord(ref endOfFile);
    bool okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
    return okay;
}
```

Apparently you are using the return value of `getNextRecord` to call `matchCustomer`. This means that `getNextRecord` must return be returning null! So let's find out why `getNextRecord` returns null:

```
public string getNextRecord(ref Boolean endOfFileFlag)
{
    string nextRecord;

    endOfFileFlag = false;
    nextRecord = reader.ReadLine();

    if (nextRecord == null)
    {
        endOfFileFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        recordReadCount += 1;
    } // end if

    return (nextRecord);
} // end getNextRecord
```

If the method `return nextRecord`, that means `nextRecord` is null. And how did you get `nextRecord`? `reader.ReadLine`!

**So the ultimate reason why `record` is null is that `reader.ReadLine` is null.**

To avoid this exception, you need to first check whether `record` is null, *then* call the method on it:

```
if (record != null) {
    data = record.Trim().Split('*');
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

In C# 6, this can be simplified to

```
data = record?.Trim().Split('*');
```

If `record` is null, `data` will be null too!

Also, note that this code is redundant:

```
String[] data = new String[5];
data = null;
```

You are creating a bunch of strings and then setting the array to null. What's the point? So you can just remove that, and change the next line to:

```
string[] data = record?.Trim().Split('*');
```